# ubuntu 14.04 sometimes hangs on purple screen when booting

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia

My laptop (toshiba tecra m11) **sometimes** hangs on a purple screen when booting. It happened like once a week, recently, but then i would just reboot and it would be fine.
Today it would persist, after trying 5 times to reboot i used a thumb drive to recover my log files. Ubuntu ran fine from the thumb drive.
After recovering the files i tried the recovery boot option, with failsafeX, but it would not work.
I also tried a normal boot with the previous kernel, which took me to the login screen but that would not let me log in, seemd like something crashed when i did. After that i tried a normal boot with the latest kernel, which worked.

I am afraid that it might be a hardware problem, but i don't know how to find out.
I've been looking into dmesg, gpu-manager.log and syslog, but i haven't found anything extraordinary.

I have a nvidia graphics card (NVS2100M), and using the propietary,tested driver (version 340.76), which is the recommended one in "additional drivers" tool.

Do you have any advice?

```
me@laptop:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 2100M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0002
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
me@laptop:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Try to install 304 driver for that card. It worked much better for me than 340.

Comment: I'd like to have a way to verify if it is going better. Do you have any tips on what log file i should look at? Or any other indication

Comment: Just install it and use for some time.

Comment: ok, giving it a try

Comment: so far so good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the older nvidia driver, version 304.125 solved my issues. 
Thank you @Pilot6 for your answer in the comments.